# Why does an extra print cause AttributeError in this python code?

Tags: python

It seems like if I take out the print, everything runs fine, but if I try to print out

```
len(set(row[5].values()))
```

it gives

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'values'
```

Here is the for loop

```
    for row in my_dict[my_options].itervalues():
        row[3] = len(set(row[3]))
        row[4] = len(set(row[4]))
        row[5] = len(set(row[5].values())) # This runs
        row[6] = len(set(row[6].values()))

        print row[5] # returns 1
        print len(set(row[5].values())) # This run into Attribute Error
```

Is print doing anything in the back that can cause error? If

```
row[5] = len(set(row[5].values()))
```

causes error, it should output error before the print line, but it didn't, which is confusing.

Any help would be appreciated.

thanks

Comment: Because after the assignment `row[5] = len(set(row[5].values()))` you do in your code, `row[5]` isn't a dict anymore but an integer?

Comment: `row[5] = len(set(row[5].values()))`
this causes row[5] to become int, so in next line values() cannot be called on row[5]

Comment: why are you using comments and not answering?

Answer (score 1):

as said in the comments
when using     `row[5] = len(set(row[5].values())) # This runs`
you actually set the value for row[5]
since the print is still inside the loop the value of row[5] will be the result of `len` (an integer)
and int doesn't have values() function